# Добавление сторонней библиотеки в Android Studio

Tags: apache, android-studio, библиотеки

Недавно начал работать в Android Studio. Необходимо подключить сторонние библиотеки ([эту](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/download_pool.cgi) и [эту](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi)), однако я не могу понять, как это делается. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для импорта .jar библиотеки в android studio скопируйте файл в папку проекта libs, нажмите правой кнопкой мыши и выберете Add As Library. Второй вариант это прописать dependencies в файле build.gradle, который лежит в корне папки app.

ПРИМЕР:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
}
```

Для поиска таких ресурсов пользуйтесь [этим](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/).